# UART Driver for STM32MP25 by EDK2

Tags: stm32, uart, edk2

I want to write a driver UART for my platform in EDK2-platform. I used an UART of EDK2, it is PL011. I made a change at code of this library, concretely at line https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/ArmPlatformPkg/Library/PL011UartLib/PL011UartLib.c#L457 by putting the address of my platform and I used an application of EDK2, it is https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/ArmPlatformPkg/PrePeiCore/PrePeiCore.c to display the content of boot process at my computer host (using minicom) and I succeeded. However when I wrote my own driver UART in EDK2-Platforms, compiled it and tested it with PrePeiCore.c, it did not work.

I think that my driver does not link to library of EDK2. So how can I make my driver UART link to library of EDK2?